# Forcing tikz/pgf to expand macros within commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

I would like to use simple macros within tikz commands, but it seems tikz doesn't expand them in the ways I would expect.

For instance, the code

```
\pgfpointcurveattime{.25}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
```

nicely returns the point one quarter of the way along the bezier curve specified by those four points.  However the code

```
\newcommand{\bcurve}{{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}}  
\pgfpointcurveattime{.25}\bcurve
```

gives an error, even though it expands to the same string.  Putting braces around \bcurve doesn't help.

What is the cause of this trouble, and more generally how can you use a macro in such a situation in tikz?

Comment: Remark: With LaTeX3 there are `tl_replace` and `regex_replace` (and `exp_args` for the auxiliary function method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My knowledge of TeX expansion is rather limited, but I think the problem is not with PGF but with TeX itself. It tries to expand `\pgfpoincurveattime` first and looks for its arguments before expanding `\bcurve`. Hence `\bcurve` is taken as one of the arguments of `\pgfpointcurveattime` and TeX looks for the other arguments in the text that follows.

So what you want to do, is to expand `\bcurve` first (once). To change the order of expansion, one uses `\expandafter`: `\expandafter\a\b` expands `\b` and adds the result after `\a` and then continues on to process `\a`. The problem here is that you want to skip over five tokens (`{.25}`), which would require a lot of `\expandafter`s:

```
\expandafter\pgfpointcurveattime\expandafter{\expandafter.\expandafter2\expandafter5\expandafter}\bcurve
```

After the execution of the `\expandafter`s, this will leave TeX with

```
\pgfpointcurveattime{.25}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
```

One possible solution to save on typing all those `\expandafters` and getting  more readable code is to save `.25` into a macro that can be skipped over in one step:

```
\newcommand*\pos{.25}
\expandafter\pgfpointcurveattime\expandafter\pos\bcurve
```

After the execution of the `\expandafter`s, this will leave TeX with

```
\pgfpointcurveattime\pos{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this solved the problem perfectly.  And now I know to be wary of expansion order issues, which should save headaches in the future.

Comment: I encountered the following further problem: `\expandafter\a\expandafter\b\c` worked fine, except then I wanted \b to be a command that took an input, so I wrote `\expandafter\a\expandafter\b{textinput}\c` and this produced errors.  How can I force evaluation of \b{textinput} in this case?  Note \b is defined as `\newcommand\b[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{test}}{\anothercommand}{}}`.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: `\expandafter` skips over single tokens, and `\b{textinput}` are 12 tokens (`\b`, `{`, `t`, ...) so you need an to adapt one of the solutions I gave to skip over these tokens (either with lots of `\expandafter`s inbetween or with some auxiliary macro).

Answer (score 4):

You can define an auxiliary macro like that:

```
\def \mycurve #1{
    \pgfpointcurveattime{.25}#1
}

\newcommand{\bcurve}{{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}}
```

then

```
\expandafter \mycurve \expandafter {\bcurve}
```

or

```
\edef \marshal{\noexpand \mycurve{\bcurve}}
\marshal
```