# pgfmath expansion - call a command from within a pgfmath environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

I am trying to define a newcommand using pgfmath. This commands calls a previously defined command but it fails. It propably has to do something with expansion.

I've read this question [about expanding pgf macros within commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18315/forcing-tikz-pgf-to-expand-macros-within-commands) but I can't get it to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mathresult}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1} \pgfmathresult}
\newcommand{\doublemathresult}[1]{\pgfmathparse{2 * \mathresult{#1}} \pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\mathresult{1}
\doublemathresult{1}
\end{document}
```

The error message is

> Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like that  but there are several possibilities but what do you want to do  ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mathresult}[1]{%
\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro\mymathresult{\pgfmathresult}}
\newcommand{\doublemathresult}[1]{%
\mathresult{#1}%
\pgfmathparse{2 * \mymathresult}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\mymathresult{\pgfmathresult}}

\begin{document}
\mathresult{2}\mymathresult

\doublemathresult{2}\mymathresult
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is where we need an expandable version of `\pgfmathparse`...

Comment: Thank you. I am just trying to make some geometry calculations. Like a library of help-functions or something. Par example, to find the intersection of 2 lines when you know a single point on each line and their slopes etc. There are more cases. I can always calculate them by hand of course, but I like my drawings to be parametrized so that I can easily make changes on them.

Comment: @Bruno, Yeah that would be great