# Is it possible to use a macro to name a TikZ node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, nodes

Is it possible to use a macro to name and reference TikZ nodes.
For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (0) at (0,0) {X};
    \node (\mymacro{2}{3}) at (1,2) {Y};
    \draw (\mymacro{2}{3}) -- (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Where `\mymacro` is (for example):

```
\newcount\counterA
\def\mymacro#1#2%
{\counterA=#1\relax%
\advance\counterA by#2\relax%
\the\counterA}
```

The actual calculation that my macro computes uses `\loop\ifnum` (which I think) means I cannot use the solution in [Modular arithmetic on node names in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/modular-arithmetic-on-node-names-in-tikz) without defining a new `\pgfmathMyMacro` function.

Is this a limitation of TikZ or is there some `\edef` or `\expandafter` black magic I could use?

Comment: Never put `\newcount` in a definition of this kind: you are reassigning every time the same name to a new counter register. It's difficult to say something more, you should offer more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to compute a number and then use the number as the name for a TikZ node. 

I hoped that how the macro is implemented would not matter. I have implemented the function in several different ways, such as recursive macro definitions with edef, TikZ maths, and Tex counters (as shown here). None worked.

However <code>\def\myothermacro#1#2{#1AAA#2}</code> works fine I must be doing something bad with Tex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is due to expansion.  TikZ names the node via an `\edef` so your macro for determining the node has to be expandable in an `\edef`.  I don't know the exact rules of what is and isn't expandable, but your macro using `\count` is not expandable.  You can see this by doing:

```
\def\test#1#2{%
\countA#1
\advance\countA by #2
\the\countA}
\edef\testit{\test{2}{3}}
\show\testit
```

The result is:

```
> \testit=macro:
->\countA 2 \advance \countA by 3 0.
```

Anything using `\pgfmathparse` is also not expandable, and I'd guess that whatever else you tried was not expandable.

Fortunately, those LaTeX3 gurus are masters of expansion and their integer stuff seems to be expandable.  Thus:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\mymacro#1#2%
{\int_eval:n {#1 + #2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\edef\testit{\mymacro{2}{3}}
\show\testit
```

Result:

```
> \testit=macro:
->5.
```

And, indeed, the following works.  The node is correctly labelled `(5)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27769/86}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcount\countA
\def\mymacro#1#2%
{\int_eval:n {#1 + #2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (0) at (0,0) {X};
    \node (\mymacro{2}{3}) at (1,2) {Y};
    \draw (\mymacro{2}{3}) -- (0);
    \draw (5) -- +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, nice to know! In one implementation I built the answer in binary with \pretocmd and \edef which worked. Now I know why converting to decimal with \pgfmathbasetodec broke it. I see lots of interesting stuff in expl3. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\mymacro}[2]{#1+#2}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (0) at (0,0) {X};
    \node (\mymacro{2}{3}) at (1,2) {Y};
    \draw (\mymacro{2}{3}) -- (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As Andrew mentions, this unfortunately results in the node being named `2+3` and not `5`.  To fix this, I attempted to use the solution from this question on [pgfmath expansion - call a command from within a pgfmath environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20265/pgfmath-expansion-call-a-command-from-within-a-pgfmath-environment) as follows:

```
\newcommand{\mathresult}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro\mymathresult{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\newcommand{\mymacro}[2]{%
    \mathresult{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{#2 + \mymathresult}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mymathresult{\pgfmathresult}\mathresult%
}%
```

but this results in a `Incomplete \iffalse` when it is used.  I simplified the above as much as I could but could not eliminate that error message.

See follow up question: [Incomplete \iffalse using pgfmath naming a TikZ node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27822/incomplete-iffalse-using-pgfmath-naming-a-tikz-node) which shows that you'll need to be careful in only choosing integer values, as decimal values do not work as labels.

Comment: But the node is called `2+3`, not `5`!  (If you add the line `\draw (5) -- +(3,0);` then it complains about the name.)