# Creating definition of new shapes in PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

Can somebody help me out with declaring these shapes for nodes? :
[image: symbols]

Need them as model for creation another shapes for symbols. Picked up those what I'm not able to define.Sorry there will be no MWE, I can do some but it will be pointless. Thanks for anyway you will help me because soon I will be ready for a psychiatry. :(

Comment: You should check out the `circuit` library in the `TikZ` base. And also scour their sources in order to figure out what is going on. What you are asking for is a lot of work. Try picking out one shape, draw it in normal `TikZ`, then find the most resembling one from the `circuit` library, try to convert that to your shape.

Comment: The [circuitikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) package (based on TikZ) offers you most (if not all) of the components you are looking for.

Comment: Uhm I was working with `circuit` library also, and even with `decoration.pathmorphing`.Thing is,I don't know pgf coding well so going to study Cmd Declaring New Shapes in pgfmanual 2.1 and pgfuserguide if I will work something out.My vision is to somehow declare new anchors inside and connect them. Or If can be code used for declaring [these new shapes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47236/how-to-connect-different-own-tikz-macros-together-default-names-of-node/47955#47955) write in TikZ, or possible working implement of it? Zeroth I can draw them as regular pictures but not as nodes.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina nothing useful found there. Roelof came with solution for this problem. I'm going to let him the opportunity and glory :P to post it here, or I will post it here in next days.

Answer (score 1):

Check this for 2nd image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [resistor={ohm=5}] (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```