# TikZ: computation in node name

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to place a variable number of nodes on a page, but I also want to be able to give these nodes a (integer) name.  However, I run into the problem that only certain kind of commands can appear in the label of a node (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27769/is-it-possible-to-use-a-macro-to-name-a-tikz-node)).

My naive attempt to achieve what I want is...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\n{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw, circle] (\n + 1) {4};
 \node[draw, circle] (\n + 2) [right of=4] {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

...but this gives the error message...

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named 4 is known.
```

...since the name of the node is actually "3 + 1" (or something close to it).

I found this hack...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\n{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nPlusOne}{\n + 1}
 \node[draw, circle] (\nPlusOne) {4};
 \node[draw, circle] (\n + 2) [right of=4] {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

...which has the right behavior.  However, when calling nested functions that also use this hack, they redefine `\nPlusOne` using their given value of `\n`.

### Question

What is a better way to assigned a computed integer to the label of a node?

Comment: What does the nested call look like?

Comment: Is everything inside a `\foreach` statement?

Comment: @percusse I could better answer that if I knew why you wanted to know.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Yes, most of the commands are (but not all).

Comment: Actually, there probably is NOT a way around the naming overlap from nested functions since LaTeX only has global variable names.  To avoid the name collision, I now start every variable name with the function containing it.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{n}\setcounter{n}{3}
\addtocounter{n}{1}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[draw, circle] (\arabic{n}){4};
     \addtocounter{n}{1}
     \node[draw, circle] (\arabic{n}) [right of=4] {5};
     \draw (4)--(5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

Comment: Oh, yes.  This will probably work.  Good idea.  I will try that when i get time later today.

Comment: Actually, this suffers from the problems as my hack, which is the inability to do math (i.e. how to get both `n-1` and `n` at the same time) and the counter is globally defined (so other function calls using the same counter name will cause problems).