# TikZ: Variable arithmetic result in node name

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having trouble incrementing a variable in TikZ and then using the result as part of a node name:

```
\def\x{2}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xplusone}{add(\x,1)}
\node (X\xplusone1) at (0,0) {};
\path (1, 1) edge (X\xplusone1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

seems to be parsing the final line as "X3" instead of "X31".

Comment: I assume that the line `\node (X\xplusone0)...` should be `\node (X\xplusone1)...`? Also, for questions like this, please post complete compilable minimal files. In this case, you don't need the `figure` environment, but it would save others some work if you included the preamble and the `document` environment.

Comment: Closely related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4275/86

Comment: Also closely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27822/86

Comment: Oh, and: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28228/86

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\pgfmathsetmacro` always saves its result with a decimal place, even if you're just working with integers. This will confuse TikZ, which assumes that a period separates a node name from an anchor. You should use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead, which will discard the decimal digits:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\x{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xplusone}{\x + 1}
\node (X\xplusone1) at (0,0) {};
\path (1, 1) edge (X\xplusone1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```