# Tikz foreach path between nodes starts at wrong position

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-node

This picture

[image]

has been generated by following code. In red circles the edges start/end not on the correct side of the node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

% ==================================================
% GENREAL OBLIQUE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC COORDINATE SYSTEM
% ==================================================
\makeatletter 
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{general}
{%
  {%
    \pgf@xa=0pt% point
    \pgf@ya=0pt%
    \pgf@xb=0pt% sum
    \tikz@bary@dolist#1,=,%
    \pgfmathparse{1}%
    % modified from copy
    % /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
    \global\pgf@x=\pgfmathresult\pgf@xa%
    \global\pgf@y=\pgfmathresult\pgf@ya%
  }%
}%
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (A) at (0,-2);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);

    \path foreach \na in {0,...,2} { foreach \nb in {0,...,2} {
    % Wyckoff letter 'a'
      (general cs:A=\na,B=\nb)
        node (a\na\nb) {2}
        % node     {a}
        node[yshift=0.5cm] {a\na\nb}
    % Wyckoff letter 'b'
      \ifnum \nb<2
       (general cs:A=\na,B=\nb+0.5)
       node (b\na\nb) {2}
        % node {b}
        node[yshift=0.5cm] {b\na\nb}
      \fi
    }
    };

    % PROBLEM
    \foreach \nb [evaluate=\nb as \nbnext using \nb+1] in {0,...,2} {
      \ifnum \nb<2
        \draw (a0\nb) -- (b0\nb) -- (a0\nbnext);
      \fi
    };

    % NO PROBLEM:
    % \draw (a00) -- (b00) -- (a01);
    % \draw (a01) -- (b01) -- (a02);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There is no problem when I use the commented code

```
\draw (a00) -- (b00) -- (a01);
\draw (a01) -- (b01) -- (a02);
```

[image]

I think my foreach loop produces the exact same code as I would write manually and I am completely suprised that tikz struggles here.

**Update due to answer by Schrödinger's cat**:

As pointed out simple integer arithmetic still results in a fixed point width number, e.g. `1+1=2.0`. For instance, this is implicitly shown in section 95.3.1 *Basic artihmetic functions* of the pgf/tikz documentation of v3.1.5b:

> 81.0 `\pgfmathparse{add(75,6)} \pgfmathresult`

It can be verified by printing `a0\nbext` as the content of a node.

In this cirumstance this has the consequence  that `.0` is interpreted as anchor specification. The pgf/tikz documentation (Section 17.2.1 Syntax of the Node Command) already says that periods should not occur in node names:

> Assigns a name to the node for later reference. Since this is a “high-level” name (drivers never know of it), you can use spaces, number, letters, or whatever you like when naming a node. Thus, you can name a node just 1 or perhaps start of chart or even `y_1`. Your node name *should not* contain any punctuation like a dot, a comma, or a colon since these are used to detect what kind of coordinate you mean when you reference a node.

Related questions:

- [TikZ: Variable arithmetic result in node name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29527/tikz-variable-arithmetic-result-in-node-name)
- [node names and nested loops in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28228/node-names-and-nested-loops-in-tikz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the usual problem that, if you do not explicitly say you want integers, Ti*k*Z adds `.0`, which gets interpreted as an anchor, the `east` anchor in this case. All I did was to replace

```
[evaluate=\nb as \nbnext using \nb+1]
```

by

```
[evaluate=\nb as \nbnext using {int(\nb+1)}]
```

to obtain

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

% ==================================================
% GENREAL OBLIQUE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC COORDINATE SYSTEM
% ==================================================
\makeatletter 
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{general}
{%
  {%
    \pgf@xa=0pt% point
    \pgf@ya=0pt%
    \pgf@xb=0pt% sum
    \tikz@bary@dolist#1,=,%
    \pgfmathparse{1}%
    % modified from copy
    % /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
    \global\pgf@x=\pgfmathresult\pgf@xa%
    \global\pgf@y=\pgfmathresult\pgf@ya%
  }%
}%
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (A) at (0,-2);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);

    \path foreach \na in {0,...,2} { foreach \nb in {0,...,2} {
    % Wyckoff letter 'a'
      (general cs:A=\na,B=\nb)
        node (a\na\nb) {2}
        % node     {a}
        node[yshift=0.5cm] {a\na\nb}
    % Wyckoff letter 'b'
      \ifnum \nb<2
       (general cs:A=\na,B=\nb+0.5)
       node (b\na\nb) {2}
        % node {b}
        node[yshift=0.5cm] {b\na\nb}
      \fi
    }
    };

    % PROBLEM
    \foreach \nb [evaluate=\nb as \nbnext using {int(\nb+1)}] in {0,...,2} {
      \ifnum \nb<2
        \draw (a0\nb) -- (b0\nb) -- (a0\nbnext);
      \fi
    };

    % NO PROBLEM:
    % \draw (a00) -- (b00) -- (a01);
    % \draw (a01) -- (b01) -- (a02);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could verify the addition of `.0` by printing a node with the content `{a0\nbnext}`. Do you happen to know where this is documented in the pgf/tikz documentation? The `int()` function is listed in subsection 95.3.2 *Rounding functions* of pgf/tikz 3.1.5b.

Comment: @Hotschke The `.0` is implicitly documented in all the functions you can look up except for those dealing with integers. What is relevant here is the addition, see the example  `\pgfmathparse{add(75,6)} \pgfmathresult` on p. 1031. See also the statement "The result stored in the macro \pgfmathresult is a decimal without units. This is true regardless of whether the ⟨expression⟩ contains any unit specification." on p. 1026. Note also that you can use `\the\numexpr\nb+1` instead of  `\nbnext` (but you need to be a bit careful with the delimiters of this one).