# TikZ: Coordinate calculations inside newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TikZ: Variable arithmetic result in node name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29527/tikz-variable-arithmetic-result-in-node-name)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,%
    snakes,fit,scopes,arrows,calc,shapes.misc,%
    shapes.arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,backgrounds,%
    decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\bbrect}[3]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{#1+1};
    \node[rectangle,draw,fit=(A-#1-\result.north west) (A-#1-#2.south east), inner sep = 0pt] (block#3) {}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \ttfamily
    \begin{scope}
            \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
                {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {1} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0}\\
            };
    \end{scope}
    \bbrect{1}{5}{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Inside the newcommand the entry A[i,i+1] is accessed, but this gives "illegal unit of measure" error.

Comment: Use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`.  (Disclaimer: this might only work with PGF2.10, I don't remember when the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` macro was introduced.)

Comment: Here's a few related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28242/86 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29527/86 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27822/86 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4275/86 (The first and second contain explanations as to *why* to do this.)

Comment: As this is closely related to the questions that I linked to, and an answer here would not add anything to what is already at those questions, we'll (probably) close this question as a duplicate of one of those to make it easier for others to find the answer to this sort of problem (which, as you can probably guess, is quite a common one!).